# R: need help matching up table rows and getting differences

Tags: r

I have chromatographic data in a table organized by peak position and integration value of various samples. All samples in the table have a repeated measurement as well with a different sample log number.

What I'm interested in, is the repeatability of the measurements of the various peaks. The measure for that would be the difference in peak integration = 0 for each sample.

The data

```
Sample Log1     Log2      Peak1    Peak2     Peak3     Peak4    Peak5
A       100      104        0.20    0.80      0.30       0.00    0.00
B       101      106        0.25    0.73      0.29       0.01    0.04
C       102      103        0.20    0.80      0.30       0.00    0.07
C       103      102        0.22    0.81      0.31       0.04    0.00
A       104      100        0.21    0.70      0.33       0.00    0.10
B       106      101        0.20    0.73      0.37       0.00    0.03
```

with Log1 is the original sample log number, and Log2 is the repeat log number.

How can I construct a new variable for every peak (being the difference PeakX_Log1 - PeakX_Log2)?

Mind that in my example I only have 5 peaks. The real-life situation is a complex mixture involving >20 peaks, so very hard to do it by hand.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you're trying to calculate? For example, what is `PeakX_Log1`?

Comment: From my table: the variation in Peak 1 would be a set of 3 numbers
0.20 - 0.21 = -0.01 (A)/ 0.25-0.20 = 0.05 (B) / 0.20-0.22 = -0.02 (C). I would then determine if the confidence interval of Peak 1 includes 0, showing that the measurement of that peak is repeatable.

The calculation involves matching up Peak1 of Log# 100 and Log# 104 and calculating the difference.

Comment: And in the real data, are there more recorded values for Sample `A` than just the two, as you have them in your example? Are you forced to use the values from `Log1` and `Log2` to match them up?

Comment: The Log1 number comes from our Lab system, I manually add the Log2 number, because this is supposed to be a blind test. In fact, I'm the only one who knows that sample A is run twice and what Log number it is.
There are only two measurements for sample A in the real data, but there are much more samples than 3 (A,B,C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will only have two values for each sample, something like this could work:

```
df <- data.table::fread(
  "Sample Log1     Log2      Peak1    Peak2     Peak3     Peak4    Peak5
A       100      104        0.20    0.80      0.30       0.00    0.00
B       101      106        0.25    0.73      0.29       0.01    0.04
C       102      103        0.20    0.80      0.30       0.00    0.07
C       103      102        0.22    0.81      0.31       0.04    0.00
A       104      100        0.21    0.70      0.33       0.00    0.10
B       106      101        0.20    0.73      0.37       0.00    0.03"
)

library(tidyverse)
new_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Log = ifelse(Log1 < Log2,"Log1","Log2")) %>% 
  select(-Log1,-Log2) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Peak"),names_to = "Peak") %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = value, names_from = Log) %>% 
  mutate(Variation = Log1 - Log2)

new_df
# A tibble: 15 × 5
   Sample Peak   Log1  Log2 Variation
   <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 A      Peak1  0.2   0.21   -0.0100
 2 A      Peak2  0.8   0.7     0.100 
 3 A      Peak3  0.3   0.33   -0.0300
 4 A      Peak4  0     0       0     
 5 A      Peak5  0     0.1    -0.1   
 6 B      Peak1  0.25  0.2     0.05  
 7 B      Peak2  0.73  0.73    0     
 8 B      Peak3  0.29  0.37   -0.08  
 9 B      Peak4  0.01  0       0.01  
10 B      Peak5  0.04  0.03    0.01  
11 C      Peak1  0.2   0.22   -0.0200
12 C      Peak2  0.8   0.81   -0.0100
13 C      Peak3  0.3   0.31   -0.0100
14 C      Peak4  0     0.04   -0.04  
15 C      Peak5  0.07  0       0.07
```